# Cast object[] to generic T

Tags: c#, generics, cosmos

We're overriding the default Cosmos serialiser so we can put in custom schema on the fly migrations for cosmos documents when being read from Cosmos.

We've done this by creating our own `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosSerializer`.

Works well when reading a single document, but when deserialising an array of documents, when `public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)` is called, the type of `T` is an array of a type.

Anyway, so we loop through each document and do the schema upgrade, and end up with a `object[]`, however the compiler won't allow a conversion of `object[] to T` even though the objects are all of element array type. Trying to instead do the conversion as a `(T)(object)object[]` will compile but the conversion fails with `Unable to cast object of type System.Object[] to type OurCustomType[]`.

Relevant code:

```
    public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        using (stream)
        {
            if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            {
                return (T)(object)stream;
            }

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                {
                    var jsonSerializer = GetSerializer();
                    return Deserialise<T>(jsonSerializer.Deserialize<JToken>(jsonTextReader));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private T Deserialise<T>(JToken jToken)
    {
        switch (jToken.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                var canUpgradeObject = typeof(T).GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IUpgradeableCosmosItem));
                return canUpgradeObject ? (T) UpdateSchemaVersionToCurrent(jToken.ToObject<JObject>(), typeof(T)) : jToken.ToObject<T>();
            case JTokenType.Array:
                var elementType = typeof(T).GetElementType()!;
                var canUpgradeArray = elementType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IUpgradeableCosmosItem));
                return canUpgradeArray ? (T)(object) UpdateSchemaVersionToCurrent(jToken.Values<JObject>(), elementType) : jToken.ToObject<T>();
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown Type to Deserialize");
        }
    }


    private static object UpdateSchemaVersionToCurrent(JObject jObject, Type t)
    {
        var obj = jObject.ToObject(t);
        var intObj = obj as IUpgradeableCosmosItem;
        while (intObj!._CurrentVersion < intObj._SchemaVersion)
        {
            var originalVersion = intObj._CurrentVersion;
            intObj.UpgradeSchemaAndIncrementVersion(intObj._CurrentVersion + 1, jObject);
            if (originalVersion == intObj._CurrentVersion)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Schema for {t.Name} was being upgraded from {originalVersion} to {intObj._CurrentVersion + 1} and the version was not updated.");
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

    private static object[] UpdateSchemaVersionToCurrent(IEnumerable<JObject> jObjects, Type t)
    {
        Type genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
        var list = (IList)(Activator.CreateInstance(genericListType))!;
        foreach (var jObject in jObjects)
        {
            list.Add(UpdateSchemaVersionToCurrent(jObject, t));
        }
        var retVal = new object[list.Count];
        list.CopyTo(retVal, 0);
        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: I think you should use two different functions here: one for single objects of `T`, and a second one for collections of `T`. In fact the method `Deserialize`  makes that switch internally anyway, so that shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: The point is, that a `T` and a `T[]` have nothing in common, so there's little use in having a common function for them, isn't it?

Comment: What should happen when i don't ask for a T[] but a List<T> or any other Enumerable Type?  I also would go for 2 methods returning T or IEnumerable<T>. That surface is way more telling what it does and how to use it without looking at the implementation or documention.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I'd agree, but unfortunately `T` is all that the `CosmosSerializer` exposers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Array.CreateInstance` and return `Array` instead of `object[]`

```
private static Array UpdateSchemaVersionToCurrent(IEnumerable<JObject> jObjects, Type t)
{
    ...
    var retVal = Array.CreateInstance(t, list.Count);
    list.CopyTo(retVal, 0);
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're very close. You just need to convert the final return object.

Instead of

```
jToken.Values<JObject>()
```

you can try converting it using the rarely-used `ArrayList`.

```
new ArrayList(jToken.Values).ToArray(typeof(T).GetElementType())
```